# Google map save marker on page refresh

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have the following code in order to click on a map and get the latitude and longitude coordinates. After clicking on the map, the marker appears at that exact point along with a radius circle around the marker. After that a cookie is being created with the coordinates.

```
 var marker;
        function placeMarker(location) {
            if (marker) {
                marker.setPosition(location);
            } else {
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: location,
                    map: map
                });

                var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
                    map: map,
                    radius: 24140,    // 15 miles in metres
                    fillColor: '#08aa23'
                });
                circle.bindTo('center', marker, 'position');
            }

            document.getElementById('lat').value = location.lat();
            document.getElementById('lng').value = location.lng();
            getAddress(location);
            var cookie_val = ('other_lat_lng', location.lat() + "," + location.lng())
            document.cookie = "other_lat_lng=" + escape(cookie_val);
        }
```

I was wondering if there is a way I can retain the marker position on a page refresh by using the coordinates cookie?

Comment: why you use cookie to save markers' information?

Comment: @Hikarunomemory I use the cookie for a search form

Comment: but if you somehow clear cookies, u'll lose all the markers. why not save the markers' position in database? you still can load from DB and set your markers back after page loaded

Comment: [localstorage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14266748/9461114) might help with your problem.