# Using Javascript how to store previous search history in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have implemented autocomplete feature using JQuery, but now I wanted to store last 20 searched per inputfield in browser. So, if user when focuses the suggestion will be fetched from the browser. If user types then from Rest API using ajax I am fetching the data.

```
    $("input[type='text']").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            var id = $(this.element).prop("id");
            var id2=this.element[0].id;
            var id3=$(this.element.get(0)).attr('id');
            console.log(id);
            console.log(id2);
            console.log(id3);
            var params = {'page':1,'size':"10"};
            params[id]=request.term;
            var jsonParams = JSON.stringify(params);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url:"http://localhost:5645/search",
                data: jsonParams,
                headers: {"X-CSRF-TOKEN": $("input[name='_csrf']").val()},
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(msg) {
                    //const result = new Set()
                    var result=[];
                    console.log(id);
                    console.log(msg.details)
                    console.log(msg.details.length)
                    for(var i = 0; i < msg.details.length; i++) {
                        var obj = msg.details[i];
                        
                        if(obj!=null && columnMapping[id]!=undefined && obj[columnMapping[id]]!=undefined){
                            console.log(obj[columnMapping[id]]);
                            //result.add(obj[columnMapping[id]]);
                            result.push(obj[columnMapping[id]]);
                            
                        }
                        console.log(result);
                    }
                    //response(Array.from(result));
                    response(result);
                }
                /* error: function() {
                    response([]);
                } */
        })
          },
          select: function(event, ui) {
              alert(ui.item ? ("You picked '" + ui.item.label) : "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
              return false;
            }
          }).autocomplete("instance")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
            console.log('test');
            var item = $("<div>" + item.label + "</div>")
            return $("<li>").append(item).appendTo(ul);
  };
```

Above is the jquery code which I am using for autocomplete. So, if no input is there I need to fetch from browser recent search. So, when user types unique search keys should be inserted. How I can store and retrive using javascript.

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14266730/js-how-to-cache-a-variable

Comment: Have you looked at this: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-with-cache

Comment: What do you feel is the "search" the term or the selected item?

Comment: @Twisty selected previous searches I want cache with fixed numer of elements(selected term)